# How to populate a square, symmetric DataFrame with elements from a Series based on pair names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, symmetric

In the following empty DataFrame, which is a square, symmetric matrix,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((6,6)), index=names, columns=names)
```

`df` looks like

```
    MCD   VZ  JPM   PG  WBA  NKE
MCD  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
VZ   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
JPM  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
PG   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
WBA  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
NKE  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

how to receive the corresponding elements from the last column of *a different* DataFrame, shown below, `df2.mi`, according to pair-names like `('MCD','VZ')`, as well as place the same values for `(i,j)` in those for `(j,i)` (because of matrix symmetry)? For example, `0.263357` should appear in `df` for the two places `('MCD','VZ')` and `('VZ','MCD')`.  A toy answer with only 3 names would be fine.

[image]

Alternatively, is there a common algorithm for populating a square, symmetric matrix by `for` loop, according to the `(i,j)` rules described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `pivot` and `add` values + transposed values (`.T`) to `df`.

Assuming `df2` has the structure of the DataFrame posted as a picture (values below are random):

```
z = df2.pivot('asset1', 'asset2', 'mi')
df.add(z, fill_value=0).add(z.T, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
          JPM       MCD       NKE        PG        VZ       WBA
JPM  0.000000  0.532617  0.322079  0.377284  0.242471  0.020071
MCD  0.532617  0.000000  0.504874  1.494942  0.737827  0.036683
NKE  0.322079  0.504874  0.000000  0.726165  0.255161  0.645917
PG   0.377284  1.494942  0.726165  0.000000  0.654995  0.593592
VZ   0.242471  0.737827  0.255161  0.654995  0.000000  0.107172
WBA  0.020071  0.036683  0.645917  0.593592  0.107172  0.000000
```

Comment: great answer. the final result is exactly what I want. looking at `z` by itself though, it's all jumbled up unexpectedly and not sure what I'm looking at, or how its transpose, also randomly jumbled up, helps create the final result

Comment: If `df2` was changed from what is shown in the second image to having two indexes (which were the first two columns): `df2.set_index(['asset1', 'asset2'], inplace=True)`, how can I make `z = df2.pivot('asset1', 'asset2', 'mi')` work again?

Comment: `z` is basically just a pivoted version of `df2` (same thing you would get with pivot table in Excel), and when we `add` it to `df` the values are aligned by index and column, so we get the same order of indexes and columns as in `df`

Comment: Regarding your question with `set_index`, I think the most straightforward way would be to `reset_index` before the `pivot`, i.e. `df2.reset_index().pivot('asset1', 'asset2', 'mi')`

Comment: Right now, that's what I'm doing due to the two indexes placed in `df2`, however, the line 
`reset_index` has to be repeated twice because there are two indexes. any way to reset two indexes at the same time?

Comment: Or, as an alternative, if 'asset1' and 'asset2' are now in the index, we can `unstack` 'asset2' to get the same thing: `df2['mi'].unstack('asset2')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227206/discussion-between-perl-and-develarist).